# Setting @Font-Face From C# Code Behind

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, font-face

In my stylesheet I have this declared

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'light';
    src: url('Fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.otf') format('opentype');
}
```

Now in my C# code behind I try to set the class like this

```
row.CssClass = light;
```

But I get a compile error of

> The name 'light' does not exist in the current context

Is it possible to reference a css class @font-face from C# codebehind?

**EDIT**
This is how I am attempting to use this - I have tried the below

```
.lightfontface {
    font-family: 'light';
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'light';
    src: url('Fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.otf') format('opentype');
}

row.CssClass = lightfontface;
```

Comment: Why do this in a code behind instead of referencing a stylesheet in HTML? Just asking

Comment: @trebleCode - because this is for the formatting of a RadGrid on export to pdf - do not need it visually displayed on the page, just need it formatted this way for export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your

```
row.CssClass = light;
```

needs to be

```
row.CssClass = "className";
```

and your css will need a .className entry.

Imagine your html row:

```
<tr class="className">stuff</tr>
```

Your CssClass assignment is assigning the value to class, and your css can use a class selector to format that row.

To sum up some of the comments, the style sheet entry should simply be:

```
.className { font-family: 'light'; }
```

Ordering on your style sheet is important.  Put the font-face definition above the .className style entry. See: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order

Comment: how would I define that in my stylesheet.css?  If I attempt to add a .classnametest {@font-face {
    font-family: 'light';
    src: url('Fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.otf') format('opentype');
} } I get a visual error of unexpected @ block in the style rule

Comment: your css entry for the class does not need the @font-face definition

Comment: I tried to add in a .className entry like this .lightfontface {
    font-family: 'light';
} - but if I try to call lightfontface from my C# I get a compile error of 'lightfontface' does not exist int he current context

Comment: how are you "calling" it from C#?  In C# the CssClass = "stringValue".  the .lightfontface entry you have in previous comment is what should go in your css style sheet

Comment: I think I am following you, but still getting an error.  See my edit.

Comment: @BoJackHorseman no it appears you're not following him lol. Set the class via string not variable. In the css make your rule..

Comment: try putting the font-face definition first.  style sheets are consumed top to bottom, and earlier entries are not allowed to be overridden by later ones. ie at the time of consuming your .lightfontface style the font-family 'light' is not defined.  see https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order